# Parsing js css and img sources from url

Tags: php, parsing

I want to get all javascript, css and image sources from an url. I am using simple dom parse for this. This is my current code:

Load url:

```
   $html = file_get_html($n);
```

Parse javascript sources:

```
foreach($html->find('script') as $element){ 
    $value = $element->src;
        if ($value != null){        
            if (strpos($value, '//') === 0) {
            } else {
                if(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                  $array[] = strip_tags($value);
                } 
                else {
                  $array[] = strip_tags($n.$value);  
                }       
            }
        }
    }
```

Parse image sources:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){ 
    $value = $element->src;
        if ($value != null){
            if (strpos($value, '//') === 0) {
            } else {        
                if(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                  $array[] = strip_tags($value);
                } 
                else {
                  $array[] = strip_tags($n.$value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Parse css sources:

```
foreach($html->find('link') as $element){ 
    $value = $element->href;
        if ($value != null){
            if (strpos($value, '//') === 0) {
            } else {    
                if(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                  $array[] = strip_tags($value);
                } 
                else {
                  $array[] = strip_tags($n.$value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My only problem is with parsing css, i would like to use something like this - `foreach($html->find('link rel="stylesheet"') as $element)` , but its not working that way. Is there a better (more accurate or appropriate) way to parse these things?

Comment: Did the answer below work?

Comment: sorry for the long response, yeah it works , thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `$html->find('link[rel=stylesheet]')`